# How to cross compile C to i386 on windows?

Tags: c, windows, assembly, gcc, cross-compiling

I am following a tutorial to create an operating system in C (and a little assembly), and since most of this stuff is done on linux I am having a hard time getting the various tools to work on windows.  So far I am just trying to compile the code from the tutorial, and I haven't made any changes yet.  This is the kernel (which gets loaded by an asm bootsector):

```
void dummy_test_entrypoint() {
}

void main() {
    char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
    *video_memory = 'X';
}
```

I am instructed to compile this using a gcc cross-compiler.  And when I try to use the i386-elf-gcc windows binaries: [link](https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/48964580/c0acfcb0-b39a-11e5-9a09-01064da391ff?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20200603%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200603T101747Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=f13127ab1e68915b4260e8465d18552e897c0c5a00d5a26f10683be0d5140d9d&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=49179590&repo_id=48964580&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Di386-elf-binutils-windows-x86_64.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream) using the command:

> i386-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o

it gives me the error:

> i386-elf-gcc: error: spawn: No such file or directory

This issue seems to be known, though I have no idea what that means. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have ie386-elf-gcc installed? And if you do, there's probably no entry of it in your environment variables. Look into environment variables on windows.

Comment: simply use minGW with the correct compile options.

Comment: @P__J__ : not a good idea. Although you can do it, there are many things about Windows native tool chains that add snafus that aren't a surprise with a nice cross compiler. If you use MinGW, I'd recommend installing a cross compiler there too. The OP using a cross compiler is a smart move, but it sounds like they haven't installed it correctly and or added it to his user account's PATH environment variable.

Comment: @MichaelPetch compiler != toolchain. For the OS programming 95% of the standard library cannot be used, 100% of startup code as well. In the fact you need to rewrite all functions you are going to use. So it will not matter. I would say that you are right if he was going to cross compile to another OS. But not if writes an OS

Comment: I didn't say the compiler was the tool chain. In fact there is more to the problems using tools that generates native Windows code. The tool chain happens to include binutils and gcc. That incluses the linker, the assembler, and they compiler. A ntaive tool chain that produces pe32 and pe32+ objects and exectuables have some interesting properties that make them more difficult to use fro OS deveklopment. I should know, I have written Stackoverflow posts that discuss and provide work around for a number of the issues.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the standard library. It doesn't exist whether you do development with a cross compiler and dev environment or use a native tool chain - because in both you will be making the resulting code free standing. At no point have I said anything about the C library because **I KNOW** you have to roll your own or use a third party one (there are some made by the OSDev community) if you want such functionality.

Comment: On a side note - to build an ELF cross compiler it isn't enough to build the compiler, you automatically have to build the generic ELF tool chain (most of which is in binutils) to make it work. If the OP has built a cross compiler they likely also have built the GNU assembler, linker, and other binutils tools that make up a base tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to [install WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) on Windows. WSL2 is Linux running on Windows, and is completely compatible with `gcc` (and `i386-elf-gcc`). I have personally used it myself and have found no issues using it once I installed it.

Then, you can build `i386-elf-gcc` and `i386-elf-ld` using [this shell script](https://github.com/mell-o-tron/MellOs/blob/main/A_Setup/setup-gcc-debian.sh). `i386-elf-g++` will also be built, so you can also write your OS in C++.

Make sure whenever you restart WSL2, you have `/usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/` added to you path. If it is not, you will get `-bash: i386-elf-gcc: command not found`. You can make sure this never happens by adding the following line to `~/.bashrc`:

```bash
export PATH="/usr/local/i386elfgcc/bin/:$PATH"
```

EDIT: Remember to use the `-nostdlib` flag when compiling C source files!

Comment: If you have WSL2, you can just use its native `gcc -m32 -no-stack-protector -ffreestanding`.  ELF is the native object-file format on Linux, so the native GCC is x86-64 ELF.  And with `-m32`, should behave like i686-elf-gcc, unless "i686-elf" implies some other stuff I'm not aware of.  (Or with `-m32 -march=i386`, like i386-elf-gcc).